# Set function in c++ not working

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, set

Im writing a Set class in c++(i know there is already a library this is an assignment) and similar to the one in C++ im writing a function to check if the entry being inputted is already in the set

```
void Set::insert(const Set::value_type& entry) 
{

    for (int i=0; i<used;i++)
        {
            if(data[i]!=entry && used<CAPACITY)
            {
                data[used] = entry;
                used++;
            }
            else 
            {
                throw "Out of capacity in Set and Intger already in Set";
            }
        }

}
```

What the function does is look if the number is in the set. If the number is not in the set and if used < capacity (meaning their is still room) then the number is inserted. When i use the insert function nothing happens. Could someone help me out. Maybe im approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: If there is no entry in your set, you are adding entry used times, because of your if statement. But your used grows, so your loop is stuck, and it can't get out from it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `data` appears to be a member variable, as does `used`, so we're guessing how most of this works. Provide an example that can be copy/pasted into a compiler, or use [an online C++ compiler](https://ideone.com/) to post and share your code so we can provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek That's assuming that `used` is updated automatically each iteration. If OP is stuck in an infinite loop though, that should be easy enough to diagnose by simple logging statements in the code.

Comment: Your loop doesn't test if the entry is not in the set. It just tests if any element of the set is different from the entry. To check if it's not in the set, you have to go through all the used entries, and see if you never find it.

Comment: I noticed those problems, but the problem that makes it a noop is that it loops to `used`, which is initially 0, so the outer loop never runs at all unless the `Set` is populated some other way. All the buggy logic inside the loop never gets a chance to go wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well right after I made the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, when `insert`-ing to an empty `Set`, `used` will be 0, so the loop terminates without doing anything. You don't handle the case where the value wasn't found after the loop, so it never inserts.

Even if you switched to loop to `CAPACITY`, the inner check is going to fill the whole `Set` with the same value on first run (because the `if` check's block executes, but doesn't `break` the loop, so it stores the same value over and over until it fills the `Set` or finds itself), then on subsequent `insert`s, it will immediately raise an exception for being full. Perhaps you wanted something like this?

```
void Set::insert(const Set::value_type& entry) 
{
    // If you have a membership test function, you can reuse it here instead
    // of including this loop, e.g.:
    // if (this->contains(entry)) return;
    for (int i=0; i < used;i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == entry) {
            // value already in set, nothing to do
            return;
        }
    }
    // Not already in Set, add if we have room or raise exception
    if (used < CAPACITY) {
       data[used++] = entry;
       return;
    }
    throw "Out of capacity in Set";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't replace existing values, because the new entry is put at `data[used]`, not `data[i]`.

Comment: But other than that, great minds think alike :)

Comment: @Barmar you are right , its not replacing the value im just using data[i] to check the whole array or set. And thanks a lot ShadowRanger i guess my brain was not working correctly. I now Understand my error THANKS

Comment: Oops. Fixed. It's basically "On first call, if the loop test ran to `CAPACITY`, it would fill the whole `Set` with the same value, then error in the future." It's really bad code in multiple ways.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Yeah i know(its bad code ..haha) its just for an assignment i would much rather just use the set library in c++. LOL

Answer (score 3):

When the set is initially empty, so that `used == 0`, your loop doesn't do anything, because the `i < used` condition fails immediately. So you never add the new item to the set.

And if there are items in the set, the loop adds the new entry to the set if it's different from any existing element. It adds it repeatedly for each element that it's not equal to.

What you need to do is go through the entire set, and see if a match is found anywhere. If it makes it through the entire loop without finding a match, it adds the new entry.

```
void Set::insert(const Set::value_type& entry) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<used;i++)
    {
        if(data[i] ==entry)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    // Not found, add it
    if (used < CAPACITY) {
        data[used++] = entry;
    } else 
    {
        throw "Out of capacity in Set";
    }
}
```